# Meaning of following statement in careers in stackoverflow

Tags: support, jobs

My profile in Stack Overflow Careers shows the following:

> [image]

I want to know what is the meaning of this?

Comment: That you're in the top 10% of users active within the Java tag in terms of score.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate of your question, but voted as such since it pretty much explains how it works and what the meaning is.